# New line and dollar sign in Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, newline

I know `$` is used to check if a line end follows in a **Java** regular expression.

For the following codes:

```
String test_domain = "http://www.google.com/path\nline2\nline3";
test_domain = test_domain.replaceFirst("(\\.[^:/]+).*$?", "$1");
System.out.println(test_domain);
```

The output is:

```
http://www.google.com
line2
line3
```

I assume that the pattern `(\\.[^:/]+).*$?` matches the first line, which is `http://www.google.com/path`, and the `$1` is `http://www.google.com`. The `?` makes a reluctant match (so matches the first line.)

However, if I remove the `?` in the pattern and implement following codes:

```
String test_domain = "http://www.google.com/path\nline2\nline3";
test_domain = test_domain.replaceFirst("(\\.[^:/]+).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(test_domain);
```

The output is:

```
http://www.google.com/path
line2
line3
```

I think it should give out the result `http://www.google.com`

1. `(\\.[^:/]+)` matches `http://www.google.com`
2. `.*$` matches `/path\nline2\nline3`

Where is my misunderstanding of the regex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex does not match the input string. In fact, `$` matches the end of string (at the end of `line3`). Since you are not using an `s` flag, the `.` cannot get there.

***NOTE!*** that the `$` anchor - *even without `Pattern.MULTILINE` option* - can match a position before the final line feed char, see [What is the difference between ^ and \A , $ and \Z in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4250062/3832970). This can be easily tested with `"a\nb\n".replaceAll("$", "X")`, resulting in `"a\nbX\nX"`, see [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/tv4oea).

More, the `$` end of line/string anchor cannot have `?` quantifier after it. It makes no sense for the regex engine, and is ignored in Java.

To make it work at all, you need to use `s` flag if you want to just return `http://www.google.com`:

```
String test_domain = "http://www.google.com/path\nline2\nline3";
test_domain = test_domain.replaceFirst("(?s)(\\.[^:/]+).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(test_domain);
```

Output of [this demo](http://ideone.com/vwdvwZ):

```
http://www.google.com
```

With a multiline `(?m)` flag, the regex will process each line looking for a literal `.` and then a sequence of characters other than `:` and `/`. When one of these characters is found, the rest of characters on that line will be omitted.

```
    String test_domain = "http://www.google.com/path\nline2\nline3";
    test_domain = test_domain.replaceFirst("(?m)(\\.[^:/]+).*$", "$1");
    System.out.println(test_domain);
```

Output of [this IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Qd4Ayq):

```
http://www.google.com
line2
line3
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a multiline input and trying to use anchor `$` in your regex for each line but not using `MULTILINE` flag. All you need is `(?m)` mode in front of your regex:

```
String test_domain = "http://www.google.com/path\nline2\nline3";
test_domain = test_domain.replaceFirst("(?m)(\\.[^:/]+).*$", "$1");
System.out.println(test_domain);
```

This will output:

```
http://www.google.com
line2
line3
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD7xJ3/1)

Without `MULTILINE` or `DOTALL` modes your regex: `(\.[^:/]+).*$` will fail to match the input due to presence of `.*$` since dot will not match newlines and `$` (end of line) is present after 2 newlines.